# How to paste data without adding spaces in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to add two pieces of data into one column, where one of the pieces of data is surrounded by parentheses, but whenever I attempt it in R, there is an extra space between the number added within parentheses and the final parentheses. Here is some example code:

```
#Pull in library:

library(dplyr)

#Use DNase data as example:

data_1 <- DNase

#Attempt to paste new column:

data_1$pasted <- paste(data_1$conc, data_1$density, sep = " (") %>% paste(")")

Examine data: 


print(data_1)
```

The top few rows of this print end up looking like this :

```
Grouped Data: density ~ conc | Run
    Run        conc density              pasted
1     1  0.04882812   0.017 0.04882812 (0.017 )
2     1  0.04882812   0.018 0.04882812 (0.018 )
3     1  0.19531250   0.121  0.1953125 (0.121 )
4     1  0.19531250   0.124  0.1953125 (0.124 )
5     1  0.39062500   0.206   0.390625 (0.206 )
```

Comment: did you try `paste0()`?

Comment: paste0(), or sep = "" within paste

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: FYI, both techniques are demonstrated in [`?paste`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html), though I recognize the nuances of when to use `sep=` and `collapse=` can be frustrating.

Comment: `str_c` from `stringr` package also pastes without spaces by default.

Comment: in this case you would rather use `sprintf`:  `df$pasted <- sprintf('%.7f (%.3f)', df$conc, df$density)`. If you insist on using `paste` then do `paste0(df$conc, ' (', df$density, ')')` or even `paste(df$conc, ' (', df$density, ')', sep = '')`